# DNN 8 scheduler errros on azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dotnetnuke

I remember reading that the DNN platform edition struggles with the MS Azure web app environment in regards to the scheduler tasks.

this quote comes for [this DNN connect blog](http://dnn-connect.org/blogs/azure-web-sites-sharing-experiences)

> The DNN Platform / Community scheduler does not support Azure Web
>   Sites as the server names running the web site are ever changing as
>   Azure scales up and down, or upgrades underlying machines. There is a
>   solution for Evoq.

I am getting the following scheduler errors in my DNN instances on Azure:

> THREAD ID:59
>   TYPE:DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchEngineScheduler,DOTNETNUKE
>   EXCEPTION:Lock obtain timed out:
>   NativeFSLock@D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Search\write.lock

It is happening A LOT.  THis is on a 08.00.04 version

I am also getting the following error on a 08.00.01 version

> TYPE:DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.PurgeScheduleHistory, DOTNETNUKE
>   EXCEPTION:Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior
>   to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

My question is whether dnn platform's scheduler works properly in the azure web app environment, and what version saw this delivered.  This will help me in getting these errors resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We often host Test and QA Evoq environments in Azure and the machine names do change, therefore require us to reactivate licensing. But these are on the Free or Shared [pricing tiers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/).  I believe if you move to Basic and above, the environment should be dedicated.  You can also confirm with DNN Corp on this because their own OnDemand hosting uses Azure.

The Search write-lock error I have seen on other environments so I don't believe it's an Azure problem necessarily.  For this issue, restart the app pool and delete all files in the App_Data\Search folder.  Then start the site, go to Settings > Site Settings > Search and click the Re-index Content button.  Then start the Site Crawler job from the scheduler.  Ensure in Site Settings > Servers > Server Settings > Web Servers, that only the current server name is there -- delete any old server names.  In Settings > Scheduler, edit the Search: Site Crawler task.  In the Servers textbox, you can enter the name of the server so that it ensures it only runs on that server to ensure no overlap in processing (thinking it's in webfarm mode).